# How to use a custom theme for error pages?

Tags: cakephp, error-handling, themes, cakephp-3.2

I am developing an application which uses themes for layouts, and I need to use custom themes for all the error pages too.

Looking at [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#exception-renderer), I see that I can change layout fairly easily by using

```
$this->layout = 'mylayout';
```

in the error page itself, but I need to change the theme too. I have tried with

```
$this->theme = 'mytheme';
```

but the error page is still using the default theme, so I guess this is not the right way to set it.

What is the correct way to set a theme for error pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Themes**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/themes.html) are easiest to be set via the `Controller.beforeRender` event, or for earlier CakePHP versions, via the `Controller::$theme` property.

The default exception renderer uses a new controller instance for handling errors, therefore you can for example

### Create a custom error controller and add a listener/callback

One option would be to create a custom error controller where you can set the theme as you would in a regular controller. By default CakePHP will use `\App\Controller\ErrorController` if it exists, so all you'd need to do would be to create the controller.

**src/Controller/ErrorController.php**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class ErrorController extends Controller
{
    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        $this->viewBuilder()->theme('ErrorThemeName');
    }
}
```

Done, all exceptions should now use the `ErrorThemeName` theme.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Error & Exception Handling > Creating a Custom Controller to Handle Exceptions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#creating-a-custom-controller-to-handle-exceptions)**

### Create a custom exception renderer and add a listener to the controller

You could also create a custom/extended exception renderer, and override `ExceptionRenderer::_getController()`, and add a proper listener for the `Controller.beforeRender` where you can set the theme.

**src/Error/AppExceptionRenderer.php**

```
namespace App\Error;

use Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer
{
    protected function _getController()
    {
        $controller = parent::_getController();
        $controller->eventManager()->on('Controller.beforeRender', function (Event $event) {
            $event->subject()->viewBuilder()->theme('ErrorThemeName');
        });
        return $controller;
    }
}
```

**config/app.php**

```
// ...
'Error' => [
    'exceptionRenderer' => '\App\Error\AppExceptionRenderer',
    // ...
],
// ...
```

See also

**[Cookbook > Error & Exception Handling > Using the exceptionRenderer Option of the Default Handler](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#using-the-exceptionrenderer-option-of-the-default-handler)**

Comment: ndm, you are the best! It worked perfectly. I was trying to do the same through the `AppController`, but it wasn't working... thank you!

Comment: I think that the `ErrorController` thing should go in the documentation, it is a simple and useful tip for someone in my situation...